# Static array declared but method cannot work

Tags: java, arrays, methods, greenfoot

I have to do my homework in `Greenfoot`. 
This part means that I have to save the position of `Chess` and then click reset. 
Then, I have to choose load to put back the pieces of chess in the position they had before reset.
Since I don't know the exact size of the array, I know I can use `List` but it isn't allowed in the homework.

Nothing showed up on the screen but there is no error message.

Assume I have a class called `Chess`.

```
static Actor[] allChess;

public void save() // this is the save
{
    Actor[] allChess = GWorld.getAllObjects("Chess");
}

public void load() // this is the load
{
    if (allChess != null)
    {
        for (int i=0; i < allChess.length; i++)
        {
            Chess ch = (Chess) allChess[i];
            GWorld.addOneObject(new Chess(ch.color, ch.rank), ch.getX(), ch.getY());
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Chess is a sub-class of Actor
This whole block is declared in the World.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`allChess` is redeclared as a local variable in `save()`. Do like this :

```
public void save() // this is the save
{
     allChess = GWorld.getAllObjects("Chess");
}
```